# Centralizers of $\mathbb{F}_q$-rational semisimple elements of a finite group of Lie type

Tags: finite-groups, algebraic-groups, finite-fields

Let $\mathbb{G}$ be a connected reductive $\mathbb{F}_q$ algebraic group over its algebraic closure $\bar{\mathbb{F}_q}$, and $\mathbb{T}$ be an $\mathbb{F}_q$-defined maximal torus. Let $\Phi$ be the root system of $\mathbb{G}$ wrt $\mathbb{T}$, and, given $g\in\mathbb{T}$, put $$\Phi(g)=\lbrace\alpha\in \Phi:\alpha(g)=1\rbrace.$$

There is a very clean criterion by Deriziotis for which closed subsystems $\Sigma\le \Phi$ can occur as $\Phi(g)$ for some $g\in \mathbb{T}$; namely, these are precisely the subsystems $\Sigma\le \Phi$ which admit a basis which is a subset of the set of affine simple roots of $\Phi$, and all such subsystems occur for some $g\in \mathbb{T}$. These are often called *pseudo-Levi* subsystems.  Furthermore, if $g\in\mathbb{T}(\mathbb{F}_q)$, then $\Sigma$ is stable under the action of the Frobenius map associated with the $\mathbb{F}_q$-structure on $\mathbb{G}$.

> **Question** Given a subsystem $\Sigma\le \Phi$ as in the last paragraph, stable under the Frobenius map, does there exist $g\in \mathbb{T}(\mathbb{F}_q)$ for which $\Sigma=\Phi(g)$? Do there exist counterexamples for this?

**What I know by now:** If $\Sigma=\Phi(g)$ is a Levi subsystem, meaning that it has a basis of simple elements of $\Phi$ then one can always take $g$ to be $\mathbb{F}_q$-rational. To show this, one can compute the dimension of the subgroups $$\mathbb{T}_{\Sigma'}=\bigcap_{\alpha\in \Sigma'}\ker(\alpha)\le \mathbb{T}$$
for all $\Sigma\le \Sigma'\le \Phi$, and verify that
$$\dim\mathbb{T}_{\Sigma'}\le \mathrm{rk}(\Phi)-\mathrm{rk}(\Sigma),$$
with equality iff $\Sigma'=\Sigma$, and, consequently, deduce that $\mathbb{T}_{\Sigma}^\circ\setminus(\bigcup_{\Sigma<\Sigma'}\mathbb{T}_{\Sigma'})$ is irreducible of dimension $\mathrm{rk}(\Phi)-\mathrm{rk}(\Sigma)$, and therefore admits an $\mathbb{F}_q$-rational point.

In the more general case, where $\Sigma$ is merely pseudo-Levi, this argument fails more-or-less completely. However, in all cases I have computed thus far it seems that one can find elements $g\in\mathbb{T}$ with $\Phi(g)=\Sigma$ whose representing matrices only have the entries $0,1$ and $-1$... I wonder if maybe there is a simpler argument that my dimension computation above overshoots.

Comment: The quantifiers aren't entirely clear for your question—you want to *fix* $\mathbb T$, right?  Also, do you really mean to switch from $\mathbb F_q$ to $\mathbb F_p$?  (It's unclear to me, because you refer to "a $\mathbb F_q$-group defined over $\bar{\mathbb F}_q$"—I'm not sure what to make of that—so I'm not sure how one even would speak of $\mathbb F_p$-rational points; and then your last paragraph starts off talking about $\mathbb F_p$-rationality, and then ends with $\mathbb F_q$-rationality.)

Comment: Oh sorry, there are several mistakes here.. I'll edit

Comment: However, I do want to fix $\mathbb{T}$ in this question

Comment: I still think there are some mistakes:  what does "a connected reductive $\mathbb F_q$ algebraic group over its algebraic closure $\bar{\mathbb F}_q$" mean?  I think you just mean "a connected reductive algebraic group over $\mathbb F_q$".  Also, I think you mean to say that Deriziotis (not Deriztiois) characterised the groups that can occur as $\Phi(g)$ for some $g \in \mathbb T(\bar{\mathbb F}_q)$ (not for some $g \in \mathbb G$).

Comment: With no conditions on $q$, you will run into problems.  For example, for $\mathbb G = \operatorname{SL}_2$ with $q = 2$, the only rational element of the diagonal torus is the identity element, so you cannot realise $\Sigma = \emptyset$.  Would you be interested in a "large-$q$-only" condition?  (I don't know if it holds—it might even be a "large-$p$-only" condition—but such results are more likely when dealing with rationality than uniform ones.)

Comment: Yes, I'm definitely okay with large p only conditions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @LSpice already pointed out, you need $q$ to be sufficiently large even in the case of a Levi subgroup. Just take $G = \operatorname{GL}_n(\overline{\mathbb{F}}_q)$ and $G^F = \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ under the usual Frobenius endomorphism. If $T \leqslant G$ is the maximal torus of diagonal matrices then $(\mathsf{C}_{q-1})^n \cong T^F = C_G(s)$ for some semisimple element $s \in G^F$ if and only if $q-1 \geqslant n$. That is because $s$ needs $n$ distinct eigenvalues to be regular.

Deciding the exact conditions for your subgroup to be realisable as the centraliser of a rational semisimple element involves a detailed case by case analysis. For the exceptional groups Frank Lübeck's GAP calculations [Centralizers and numbers of semisimple classes in exceptional groups of Lie type](http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/%7EFrank.Luebeck/chev/CentSSClasses/index.html) are invaluable here. But if you're just interested in a "$q$ sufficiently large" statement then this was obtained by Deriziotis's advisor R. W. Carter in Corollary 20 of the following paper:

- "[Centralizers of semisimple elements in finite groups of Lie type](https://doi.org/10.1112/plms/s3-37.3.491)", Proc. London Math. Soc. (3), vol. 37, (1978), 491–507.

It is essentially a counting argument. It's pointed out explicitly in Theorem 21 that a Levi subgroup is always the centraliser of a rational semisimple element assuming $q$ is sufficiently large.

Another paper that streamlines things here is the following paper of Bonnafé:

- "[Quasi-isolated elements in reductive groups](https://doi.org/10.1081/AGB-200063602)", Comm. Algebra (7), vol. 33, (2005), 2315–2337.

This paper makes parts of Carter's and Deriziotis' work much clearer. In particular, Bonnafé gives a clean construction for elements whose centraliser is not contained in any proper parabolic subgroup.